# .net core - Swagger - Add custom parameter to Authorization popup

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

TL;DR

Is there a way to add an extra custom parameter text-box in the authorization like so?
[image]

---

On client authorization, I have a custom token request validator, ICustomTokenRequestValidator which checks some for some extra info in the request's context. When I do the requests through postman I can have these parameters inside the request (form-data etc) and I can get the required extra parameter and do my custom validation.

I didn't find a way to do this through swagger, is there a way to add a parameter (custom text box) when I want to make a request for authorization?

Comment: Not out-of-the-box. You'll need to fork Swagger UI, implement this functionality yourself & use your custom fork with Swashbuckle.

Comment: @Helen thought so, thank you! is there any other way around it? Pass the information somehow in a different way?

Comment: Possibly using a [request interceptor](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#use-client-side-request-and-response-interceptors).

Comment: @Helen, thanks again :) that wont work for my case, the information I want could change for each authorization request, I cant have it hardcoded, I would need a convenient place for that value to be in, or ideally given from a user